# Is the adverb “yet” redundant?

Tags: adverbs

I mention some project and I say, “It is not finished.” Is adding the adverb “yet” provide anything extra (perhaps, implying that some people are still working on it, versus it is abandoned; or perhaps it is expected to be finished sometime relatively soon, versus some indefinite time in the future), or is it redundant?

Comment: Yes, "yet" here would have the meaning that the project is expected to be finished. Work may have slowed or paused, but the project is not abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't redundant.

There are many unfinished works which will never be finished for a variety of reasons. For example, *Schubert's Unfinished Symphony*.

Saying something is unfinished merely tells its current state but says nothing about its future.

Saying something is *yet to be finished* implies that it will be finished at some point in the future. "It is not finished *yet*" has the same meaning.